# Probability question about the stock market

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I want to buy some shares on the stock market. I want to predict whether the price will go up or go down so I look at 3 indicators on my chart.
1 indicators says that there's a 55% chance the price will go up. 1 says there's a 65% chance it will go up and one says there's a 60% chance of a price rise. all indicators are equally reliable.

What can I then say about my total chance of the price going up? Can I treat these indicators as independent? (I don't think so because they all are in relation with the price.) But does that mean I just have to take the average of the 3? so in this case 60%?

But what about 1000 indicators all saying the chance of a price rise is 60%? Intuitively it seems to me that would mean the total odds are bigger than 60%, is that right?

And if there's no mathematically 'correct' way to calculate this, how could I approach a solution then?

Comment: This question is not well defined since you haven't specified what you mean by "reliable"

Comment: it's not possible to put a number on the reliability, it is unknown. The only thing that is known is that they're equally reliable.

Comment: yes but I didn't get any more answers there so I put it in a new question. also, the question is slightly different here, I asking for more of an approach or explanation instead of one answer.

Comment: That is not well defined, and hence you can't get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Okay then how I can define it better? It's a hypothetical question so I can try to define it better if I know how.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as "Too Broad", as there are quite a few unstated assumptions in your question, with each one perhaps requiring quite a bit of explanation.  For example, what do you mean by "equally reliable"?  Do you want to weight these probabilities equally?  Do you assume that the "spread" of each of these measures is the same?  Something else?  Narrowing down your problem significantly would allow people to give better answers, and might also help you to clarify what, exactly, you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All indicators are equally reliable" seems to me that in your decision making process, they should have equal weight.  So I would take the average of $\frac{55\% +60\% +65\%}{3}=60\%$

Alternatively, it could be the case that each indicator is accurate up to a confidence interval? So for each indicator $i$, the change of price increase is $x_{i}\% \pm \Delta_{i}\%$.  And so you could maybe consider the average chance and average confidence interval $$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}\%) \pm \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\Delta_{i}\% )$$ or the average chance with the worst confidence interval $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}\%) \pm max_{1\leq j \leq n}(\Delta_{j}\%)$$

These are just some thoughts, it could be useful to have more context.  Again, the wording "all indicators are equally reliable" suggests to me that they should weigh equally in the decision making process

Concerning your question *"But what about 1000 indicators all saying the chance of a price rise is 60%? Intuitively it seems to me that would mean the total odds are bigger than 60%, is that right?"*.
- No I don't agree.  If we had 1000 indicators saying the same thing, we could probably make a statement that "The odds of stock price increasing is probably very very close to 60%".  Ie, the confidence interval gets smaller as more indicators agree

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me understand the problem with my question and why I couldn't get my head around it, thus solving my actual question.